# How to put bmp file into array c++ c

Tags: c++, bmp

how can I put the file.bmp to array using standard lib c++ or c whithout windows.h ect

edit
I want to get bmp colors  to array  change the array and put to bmp using standard lib

Comment: `file=fopen("file.bmp", "rb"); fread(buffer, 1, filesize, file);`

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do. Do you want the actual bytes of file data in BMP format in the array? Or do you want the image data in the array in some other kind of format?

Comment: Is this homework? By colors do you mean pixel values?

Comment: I think what he wanted is to get the exact hex values (as in color/grayscale intensity) of each pixel, so opening the file as a pure binary object will do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a binary stream:

```
#include <fstream>

char buffer[100];
ifstream myFile ("myImage.bmp", ios::in | ios::binary);
myFile.read (buffer, 100);

myFile.close();
```

However, parsing it will be a bit trickier if you insist on doing it that way. I suggest you look into a generic C++ image library, such as the [boost GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/gil/doc/) (doesn't support bmp) or [this open source bmp library](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/).

If you are unable to use any third party or OS-specific libraries, you will have to parse the data yourself. The C++ standard libraries don't include anything to do that for you. You'll have to start by familiarising yourself with the BMP structure. [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) has a good description of it.

Comment: `fstream.h` will most likely fail (i.e.: I don't know of any system where `fstream.h` exists). You meant `fstream`.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File(fileName);
//get the file length
//create a buffer big enough.
file.read(buffer, size)...
```

Of course you might not really want the bitmap file in an array, because the array would contain all the bitmap header info, not just the color map.

Now if this is homework (and I'm betting it is), then you could create a new struct that has a header section and a "map" section.. You could suss out how big the header is (i believe there is a variable in the header that tells you how big it is.)  With that in hand, you could easily grab only the map data.

I'd try it out with a CBitmap object, then dig into the code for CBitmap and pull out the bits you need.

sorry for not offering code.. I'm not in C/C++ world these days so it's not as fresh as it once was.

---

check out the docs on bitblt.. It will help you change your array.. Also a quick google search and you could have found most of this out.
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=261522  was the first hit I got on bitmap
[How to change, modify, cut and swap pixels from BITMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899246/how-to-change-modify-cut-and-swap-pixels-from-bitmap) was a bit down the page, but still.. google first, SO last.

Comment: Some will suggest the use of lib's.. Boost/mfc.. these are heavy and will bloat your app.. Not that they aren't fantastic, but be sure you need them.

Comment: You can't say `File f = new File(fileName);` in C++, unless you're using some library. C defines FILE, but you certainly can't use it like that.

Comment: Correct, boost=bloat. But if it's that or parsing your own bitmaps... But boost doesn't have a bitmap library that I'm aware of. He said no windows.h; that means no MFC. The EasyBmp library I linked to looks fairly small.

Comment: As already said, there's no `File` class in standard C++, and also you won't ever create an object like that in C++ - that's Java/C# syntax.

Comment: sorry guys.. my code was meant to be sudo..  SO made me mark it as code.  I've been deep in android (java is yuck) as of late, I am so sad.... Here.. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/FILE/

Comment: I only suggested the MFC for figuring out the structure of the bitmap.  Were this my homework, I'd use it as a testing tool.. If my data matches it (or any other lib's data), then I could be sort of assured I had it.. You can dig down in MFC, so why not steal what you can :) if you can dig down into the code of any other lib, by all means I'd use that too.  I just happen to have MFC in my head from my last project.